# Read/Load xml file by form loading using c#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I'm writing a program which add items to `DataGridView` and save the inputs to an xml file which is created by clicking button (if not exists). This works fine. But if I restart the program it should load every item to `DataGridView`. But I have to add a new item first and then all the other items are displayed. So the items won't load if Form1 load. I think I have to put some code in `Form1_Load()` but I don't have an idea. I tried to put `XElement.Load();` in `Form1_Load()` but no success. Here you can see my code:

```
XElement xmlFile;
XElement xmlnode;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xmlFile = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml");
    xmlFile.Add(xmlnode);
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml"))
    {
        using (File.Create(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml")) { }
    }

    xmlnode = new XElement("iToDo",
        new XElement("Name", txtName.Text),
        new XElement("Priority", comPrio.Text),
        new XElement("StartDate", txtStart.Text),
        new XElement("EndDate", txtEnd.Text),
        new XElement("Comment", txtComment.Text)
     );

     try
     {
        xmlFile = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml");
        xmlFile.Add(xmlnode);
     }

     catch (XmlException)
     {
         xmlFile = new XElement("ToDos", xmlnode);
     }

     xmlFile.Save(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml");
     DataSet flatDataSet = new DataSet();
     flatDataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml");
     DataTable table = flatDataSet.Tables[0];
     dataGridToDo.DataSource = table;
}
```

Someone got an idea or can give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to put this in the form1_load method:

```
 DataSet flatDataSet = new DataSet();
 flatDataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml");
 DataTable table = flatDataSet.Tables[0];
 dataGridToDo.DataSource = table;
```

I've created your app now, here's my Form1_Load method:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xmlFile = XElement.Load(@"C:\save.xml");
        xmlFile.Add(xmlnode);

        DataSet flatDataSet = new DataSet();
        flatDataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\save.xml");
        DataTable table = flatDataSet.Tables[0];
        dataGridToDo.DataSource = table;
    }
```

When I run the app, then my datagrid gets filled with the xml data.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem still remains :/

Comment: Ah nice! Thank you. Yeah I made an error. I deleted the xmlFile part >.< Works fine! Thanks :)